# SmarterASP.net - Connecting to Azure Database

Tags: azure, dns

We are hosting our website at SmarterASP.net but because of their database limitation, we are moving the database to Azure. To connect to external ports (on different servers), SmarterASP requests us to add their IP address to the list of Outgoing Ports. Microsoft's DB address is: 
[ourcompany].database.windows.net

Two questions:
1 - I shouldn't trust that the IP I got when pinging Microsoft's database dns is static and never changes, should I?
2 - Why SmarterASP tells me it's not possible to add the DNS in their firewall? According to them, it has to be the IP address. Is that common?

Comment: Looks like you are in a pickle. AzureSQL does not have the ability to have a static IP address (see e.g. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/acab9131-e6b4-4529-8130-11c141d36c26/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-to-an-sql-azure-server?forum=ssdsgetstarted), and as you are saying, SmarterASP's outgoing connections manager only allows remote IP (not domain) whitelisting. I wonder if their support can help you out. You can host a SQL server inside an Azure VM and have static IP, but that is not the same thing as the managed AzureSQL server and you'd lose out on the benefits of that.

Comment: But do you thing that SmarterASP is just trying making it harder? Seems like a simple thing to add exceptions based on DNS and not IP. They informed me that "this is how it works".